# ASP.NET Core CSS Isolation with Webpack

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webpack, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

My ASP.NET Core RazorPages project uses Webpack. I also want to use  [CSS Isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#css-isolation).

Every RazorPage `Foo.cshtml` has an associated css file `Foo.cshtml.css`. These undergo css isolation and bundling by the runtime, and placed in a subdirectory of `obj/`. The runtime appears to serve the final bundle from `wwwroot/ProjectName.styles.css` (but it isn't really there, it's an "implementation detail").

Bad option 1: use Webpack. I could rename these to `Foo.cshtml.scss` and make them available to Webpack. But I doubt it's possible (?) to compile them (in-place and unbundled) so the runtime can find them.

Bad option 2: use runtime. I could exclude these from Webpack altogether, and allow the runtime to manage them. But then I can't use scss, or minification.

*How can I use the CSS Isolation feature and Webpack simultaneously?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The CSS isolated file must be CSS - it cannot be SCSS. So install an IDE extension that compiles scss->css on save, alternatively, add this as a build step so it's available in CI. Configure it to compile in-place `SomePage.cshtml.scss` to `SomePage.cshtml.css`.
2. Disable [automatic bundling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#disable-automatic-bundling) by the runtime, by adding to the cproj file:

   ```xml
   <DisableScopedCssBundling>true</DisableScopedCssBundling>
   ```
3. Configure webpack to output another bundle, specifically for the isolated CSS files:

   ```js
   entry: {

      site:  // normal site bundle

      razor: // css files in obj/(Debug|Release)/net6.0/scopedcss/**/*.css
             // can use glob.sync() above to find all css files automatically
   }
   ```
4. Remove reference to `MyProject.styles.css` in `Layout.cshtml`, and replace it with the new webpack bundle `razor.css`.
5. Add `*.cshtml.css` to `.gitignore`

This is not ideal due to the need for the workaround in (1). However, it works perfectly.

If you have a better solution, please add it and I'll accept your answer.